# Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to execute the following simple example in Spark. However, I am getting below error

> "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[mydata]"

How do I fix this?

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql._
 import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering._
 import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler


 case class mydata(ID: Int,Salary: Int)

 object SampleKMeans {

 def main(args: Array[String]) = {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
            .appName("SampleKMeans")
            .master("yarn")
            .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  val ds = spark.read
           .option("header","true")
           .option("inferSchema","true")
           .csv("data/mydata.csv")
           .as[mydata]

   val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
               .setInputCols(Array("Salary"))
               .setOutputCol("SalaryOut")
   val a = assembler.transform(ds)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide schema information.

```
case class mydata(ID: Int,Salary: Int)

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("ID", IntegerType, false),
  StructField("Salary", IntegerType, false)))
```

Provide the above piece of code inside main method.

And your call for reading CSV will be

```
spark.read.schema(schema).csv("path").as[mydata]
```

With this, you can use your rest of the code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not seem to work. I had also tried .option("inferSchema","true") but still the same error.

Comment: Does your CSV contains headers "ID" and "Salary"? I have tried the same with Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11.6. The approach I suggested is working fine. Without inferSchema option.

Comment: Yes, it contains headers "ID" and "Salary". I tried to build with Spark 2.2.1  Scala 2.11.8 but  I am getting error that StructType is not found. Not able to import sql.types. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: to import sql.types please call import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

Comment: Thanks raj for that edit. I forgot to mention the imports of sql types in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error went off after I explicitly specified the schema. Thanks everyone for helping me out.

```
  val ds = spark.read
     .schema("Int","Int")
     .option("header","true")
     .csv("data/mydata.csv").as[mydata]
```

Comment: That's what I suggested in my answer. In the older version of Spark, defining schema has different code syntax. You should accept the answer ideally!

Comment: You were correct, Vinod. That's what I did and it worked. Thanks. When you say that I need to accept answer, is there an option to accept answer in StackOverflow ? I am not aware of that. I am new here.

Comment: I accepted the answer :-)  I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

An example you provided works on Spark 2.2.0. I guess it's not code you trying to run, but only an example for stackoverflow.
Check if your case class is top level object (and not declared inside method)

Comment: It's the code which I am trying to run. Just a learning exercise for me. I am new to Spark/Scala. I tried with Spark 2.2.1 and I am having case class outside main.